# Fluid Layouts: What image will the user download?

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

Good Day

Im using a fluid layout with Twitter Bootstrap.
Now I am using an image of say 1280*720. Now when a users that has a mobile screen of 960px and smaller, the image will obviously be resized.

Now when you resize the the screen(or view on a smaller screen), you will see in the inspect element code that the image has dimensions and another dimension nl: (natural: 1280px * 720px). So obviously the natural size is the original image size that lies on the server..

**My question:** When a user, using a mobile device that is making use of the fluid properties, views the image, will the original image be downloaded and then resized or will he be downloading the resized image to his phone? So basically - Will a user with a mobile device download a smaller size image compared to the desktop user (if it the same image/one image on the server)?

thank you!

Comment: +1 for starting with "Good Day"

Comment: haha cool thank you....I always do that...Maybe you should read all my other entries and I can get some more points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be getting the full size image, which isn't the best idea performance wise.

I use Matt Willcox's Adaptive Images script on my projects to sort this out.

http://adaptive-images.com/

It's a PHP based solution so might not be suitable for your needs but it is a good tool.

Another option is to serve up a smaller image based on either screen size or device detection.

Comment: thank you for this, appreciate. So you mean that the the smaller image should be an entirely separate image?

Comment: any other non server side solutions? CSS/Javascript maybe?

Comment: No, because by the time the client can resize the image, it's already downloaded the full image (otherwise, it has nothing to resize).

Answer (score 1):

They will be downloading the full size image, and it will be re-sized on their device.

The natural size refers to the natural size of the image that was downloaded (i.e the image being displayed)

Comment: any non server side solutions? CSS/Javascript maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure - but I don't think so; i think if an image is modified it would have to be saved somewhere (on the server) and then re-downloaded, which would lead me to believe that a non-server-side solution isn't possible